# Broken Blog Menu

Tags: wordpress

Where do you fix a menu? You can navigate away from the homepage but you cannot return via the "Home" menu item.
http://retirementpropertyinbelize.com/
The link reads retirementpropertyinbelize.com/index.php when you hover over it. Where is this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing an anchor link to home using a relative path but the other pages are in a sub folder causing it to hit the index page of that folder instead.

Change `<a href="index.php">Home</a>` to `<a href="/index.php">Home</a>`

Comment: I followed this exactly but nothing has changed. Here is that code: <div id="navigation">
<ul id="topnavigation">
<li><a href="/index.php">Home</a>
<?php wp_list_pages('depth=1&title_li='); ?>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Update: Applying fix to page.php file fixed problem. Thanks tawman and cotton.m

Answer (score 0):

The "where" to make changes this will be in your wp theme.